# Firebase Cloud Functions (Leaderboard & +10.000 Users Timeout)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

My app has a leaderboard which is daily updated with a firebase function. Now I have more then 20.000 Users and the funciton times out always (already for 550 seconds).

```
exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('every day 00:00').timeZone('Europe/Vienna').onRun( async (contextm) => {
  functions.logger.log('Positioning stated... (v.1.0.5)');
  batch = db.batch();
  const allUsers = await db.collection('users').orderBy('coins', 'desc').get();

  let i = 0;

  for (const doc of allUsers.docs) {
    batch.update(doc.ref, "rank", i);
    i += 1;

    if(i % 499 == 0) {
      await batch.commit();
      batch = db.batch();
    }
  }

  const writeResult = await batch.commit();
  functions.logger.log('Updating Leaderboard');
  return null;
});
```

How to optimize in terms of performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you maximized your [runtimeOptions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_timeout_and_memory_allocation) to the 540 seconds and 8 GB memory your only solution (I can recommend) would be to run that code on a trusted backend with the Firebase admin SDK. That is how we recaclulate our warehouse stocks every day. It takes about 30 min so it can't run on a Firebase cloud function.

Comment: The question states that they already maxed out the timeout.

Comment: Thx @DougStevenson. I just wrote it to make it sure. If someone get's to that question in future and doesn't have maxed out everything. They only way then is to do it on another trusted backend. No matter if it is something from Google or own servers.

Comment: How did you get to the fact of 30 minutes?

Comment: It's running on one of your local linux servers on a simple node script. I log the time when it starts and again when the script ends. It started with 15 min . Now it takes 30 min and increases each day as we recalculate the stock from the day the app is started using. We will change it later to recalculate only the last year.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing you can do to improve the situation in terms of performance.  The execution speed of your code is gated by the performance of Firestore.  The Firestore operations will always take as long as they take - they can't be sped up.

The only alternatives you have within GCP are:

1. Divide the problem into smaller problems, and solve each smaller problem in its own function invocation.
2. Use a different backend product other than Cloud Functions (as it is not meant for long-running operations).

For #1, you can fire off other pubsub functions to handle batches of users asynchronously from the main function.  You will have to package up a payload of data for the delegate function to work with, so that it doesn't have to repeat the first query.  Each delegate invocation can update the documents in its own more predictable amount of time (as you will limit the size of each batch).

For #2, you could instead use Cloud Run, which gives you up to [60 minutes](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/request-timeout) of time per invocation.  Or you could set up a Compute Engine instance, which would run 24/7, and you would write code to invoked an exposed endpoint in your scheduled function.